# Use Spatie/Async to response json and continue run work Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to response by async with Laravel so i use Spatie/Async after that i want continue to do another handle.

```
$pool = Pool::create();

$pool->add(function () {
return 1;
})->then(function () {
    return response()->json(['abc'], 200);
 });
foreach ($operations as $operation) {
    $pool->add(function () use ($operation) {
         return 111;
      });
  }
dd(await($pool));
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Not good idea. Dispatch job for actions after response or event with queued listener.

Comment: @Maksim i use event with queued listener but how can i response with queued listener? When i use it, queued run successful but i'm check with ajax nothing response.

Comment: No, you response in controller and dispatch events for doing actions in another handle.